# Enabling error reporting just backend

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, error

trying to delete an order, magento shows blank page. Is there a way to enable error reporting just for backend? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using this script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento

However it could be useful to enable error reporting just for backend when site is live.

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP access go to your Var/Log folder delete system.log and exception.log

Then run your admin query again. wait for the whitescreen. Then look to see if a new exception.log and system.log file has been created using FTP.

If you don't want to delete the system and exception files. The entry you're looking for should be at the bottom of the respective files.

They are time stamped.

Comment: unfortunately I did it, but I can't recognise any error about orders

Comment: Can you post the error you did get please?

Comment: unfortunately blank page :(

Comment: Is your site a live site or a development site?

Comment: live, that's why i can't enable error reporting

Comment: Another option is to rename the var folder via ftp  then try again. Did you fully resolve your issue can you now delete orders without getting a white screen?